# Pallette items are not visible in Android Studio 2.3.3

Tags: android, layout, palette

I am not finding any items such as Buttons, Text field, Layouts, Images, Checkbox, etc.
I can see only below items.

1. Menu Item
2. Search Item
3. Switch Item
4. Menu
5. Group

Please look at the screen shot at below location.
Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGzVE.png

Answer (score 0):

You are viewing a menu resource file with top element menu. So those are the only viable options. If you want to create a view with buttons, text fields, etc you need to create a layout resource file. So your xml should have a top element of LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much Ben, it would be great if you can give me a sample xml to create buttons, text fields, etc.

Comment: If you are using Android studio you can just right click on your resources folder and select new resource. In the dialog that pops up choose Layout for the resource type. This developer page will give you the info you need to get started in terms of choosing which layout type you want https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html